# Random effect glm in glmer error message

Tags: r, validation, mixed-models

This is a subset dataset where I am trying to run a glm keeping in account the random effect of some operators taking more than one measurements:

```
data<-data.frame(c("AA","AB","AC","AD","AE","AF","AG","AB","AE","AH","AI","AJ","AK","AL","AM","AD","AN","AO","AP","AQ","AR","AS","AT","AU","AJ","AM","AI","AD","AV","AW","AE","AA","AY","AP","AM","AZ","BA","BB","BC","BD","BE","BF","BG","BH","BI","BJ","BK","BF","BL","AI","AD","BM","BN","BO","AU","AM","AE","AI","AC","BP","BQ","BR","BS","AB","BT","BU","BV","LEH","AD","AZ","BW","BL","BX","BY","BZ","BR","AL","BU","AJ","CA","CB","BO","BU","BO","CC","CD","BU","CE","CF","CG","CH","BO","AX","AJ","CI","AN","CJ","BO","AJ","CK","AY","CL","CM","CL","CN","AV","CO","BP","CP","CK","BP","BF","CQ"))
colnames(data)[1]<-"op"
data$resp<-c(1,NA,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,NA,0,1,1,0,NA,0,0,0,1,NA,1,0,0,1,0,NA,NA,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,NA,1,1,1,1,0,1,0,NA,1,1,NA,1,NA,1,0,0,0,1,NA,NA,1,1,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,NA,0,1,0,1,NA,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,NA,1,0,NA,1,0,1,1,0,NA,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,1)
data$var1<-c(NA,NA,0,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA,1,0,1,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,1,0,NA,1,NA,1,0,0,0,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,0,1,NA,1,0,NA,NA,0,0,0,1,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,1,NA,1,0,0,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,NA)
data$var2<-c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,1,NA)
data$var3<-c(NA,NA,1,NA,NA,0,1,NA,1,0,NA,NA,0,1,0,NA,NA,NA,0,0,NA,0,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,0,NA,1,NA,0,0,1,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,0,0,NA,1,1,0,NA,NA,1,NA,0,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,1,NA,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0,0,0,1,NA,1,NA,NA,0,0,0,0,0,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,0,1,0,NA,NA,0,0,NA,NA,0,NA,NA)
```

When I run the first glm using glmer (from lme4) as follows:

```
summary(glmer(resp~var1+(1|op),data=data,family=binomial,na.action=na.omit))
```

I only obtain this error message

```
Warning messages:
1: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   unable to evaluate scaled gradient
2: In checkConv(attr(opt, "derivs"), opt$par, ctrl = control$checkConv,  :
   Hessian is numerically singular: parameters are not uniquely determined
Error in diag(vcov(object, use.hessian = use.hessian)) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'diag': Error in solve.default(h) : 
  Lapack routine dgesv: system is exactly singular: U[3,3] = 0
```

When I run the second glm for the second variable

```
summary(glmer(resp~var2+(1|op),data=data,family=binomial,na.action=na.omit))
```

I then obtain this other message:

```
Error in summary(glmer(resp ~ var2 + (1 | op), data = data, family = binomial,  : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'object' in selecting a method for function 'summary': Error in summary(glmer(resp ~ var2 + (1 | op), data = data, family = binomial,  : 
  pwrssUpdate did not converge in (maxit) iterations
```

If I run it for the third variable

```
summary(glmer(resp~var3+(1|op),data=data,family=binomial,na.action=na.omit))
```

then it seems to work ok, but is it true then? There must be something with the distribution of the data for which this analysis is not working. Anyone has any idea and can propose a way around it?

I might have find a way around it by running

```
summary(lme(resp~var1,random=~1|op,data=data,na.action=na.omit))
```

which seems to run ok for all 3 variables, however the results are a little different for data$var3 between glmer and lme and I am not trusting my results at this point.
I am not sure why I am getting these errors and all the explanations I could find in SO and other sites do not make much sense to me. The data is very simple but why is this not working? Is using lme appropriate?
Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case of the second one, it's fairly easy to see that the regressions *should* fail (since the predictor and outcome variables are identical):

```
> na.omit(data[c('resp','var2','op')])
    resp var2 op
7      1    1 AG
9      1    1 AE
13     1    1 AK
20     1    1 AQ
22     1    1 AS
30     0    0 AW
31     1    1 AE
42     0    0 BF
44     1    1 BH
52     1    1 BM
53     1    1 BN
74     1    1 BY
83     1    1 BU
107    1    1 CO
108    1    1 BP
112    1    1 BF
```

In the case of the first one they are almost identical although there were a few cases (two I think) with different values but with the extra structure imposed by the clustering term, it's not surprising to me that the error message was different.

In the case of the third one, there is a different problem:

```
> with( na.omit(data[c('resp','var3','op')]), table(resp,var3) )
    var3
resp  0  1
   0 22  0
   1 16 18
```

This is known as "complete separation". When `var3` is 1 there are no cases of resp being equal to 0. So the "true" odds of being 1 are Infinity. I'm guessing you got coefficients of 10 or 20 (or something in between). That's a sign of a pathological result with logistic regression, because the exponentiated coefficients (which are the odds ratios) are extremely large. Moral: You should learn to do more tabular investigations before you dive into regression modeling.

Comment: Thank you @BondedDust - this makes sense! I could figure then out that the data was not completely independent hence the weird results. Thank you!